# repopulating old input of array form laravel

Tags: laravel

I have forms and system tags, js add li element. When seend and returns error forms is clear. I have found the `old` function: `{{ old('name') }}` but that doesn't seem to work for array fields like my `multiTag` field. When using `old('multiTag')` the following error is shown:

> htmlspecialchars(): Argument #1 ($string) must be of type string, array

Is it possible to show the old value as a li in a div or ul element?

Comment: please share some code, expected output and error you are getting.

Answer (score 1):

To get a value of an array with Laravel `old()` method, parse the key of the value you need after the field name.

```
{{ old('field.0') }}
```

Or you could do something like:

```
@foreach(old('field') as $key => $field)
   {{ old('field.'.(int) $key) }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: Thanks for response. One more qestion how check how much array position?You can manually add 30 items but there is no choice of solution.

Comment: That could be like `count(old('field'))`, because old is returning the array.

Comment: You have to make a check in your controller and/or form, if you want to cap the amount of values.